# App for Google Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I have created an App for google chrome which just opens a web page. I am new in the topic
of Apps. I was thinking if it is possible to execute some linux command by using an App
in google chrome. For instance, an App which can open a terminal or open a program 
installed in my machine like Gimp, Kate, Libre Office ...

From the instructions in the web page of google I saw that the only actions for an App
are limited to open a web address but I dont know if it is possible to extend the capabilities
of the Apps,

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't apps sandboxed into the Google Chrome Process to ensure they can't affect other processes and for other security reasons. If so, you won't be able to execute programs/commands or view the User's Files unless you use some workaround such as Google's [Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/).

Google has locked down capabilities to stop malicious Web Apps from executing code and bringing malware and exploits.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [NPAPI Plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) or a custom [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) associated to Unix terminal.